# SQL SSIS How many Steps is too much

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has 27 steps, ranging from table truncating, to data importation,transformation, and a bunch of sql queries. My question is, is it better practice to keep them all in one package, or to separate the steps into individual packages?

Comment: And then the next question will be: SQL SSIS How many packages is too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general advice is to make the packages as concise and focused as possible but no smaller. Helpful, I know so here are some of my criteria on deciding if it's a new package or fits the current one.

- If the 27 step package blows up on step 26, are you humped? Can it gracefully restart or will it require multiple hours of cleanup?

If the answer is cleanup required, then I'd decompose the package into a series of smaller packages until they satisfy the restartability criteria.

- Is there logic in the package for an infrequent branch? *e.g.* I've seen packages that had a date check, if it was the purge weekend (once a year), it executed this special branch of code that was overly convoluted, complex and just sucked. That should have never been in a package that runs daily.  Another example of this was a job that daily sales. Another team attempted to add in logic that also computed month end inventory totals. Completely different subject areas and the wrong schedule to boot but they thought it was faster than spinning up a new package.
- Assuming 2008+, do you need to share the results of a lookup cache? If so, the data flows need to be in the same package.

Comment: Just voted up for this answer-especially restarting packages and separating subject areas. And have one technical thing to add: opening package (in both design time and run time) results in validation of whole package (all tasks). This adds time overhead for both developers and production environment and most likely one of the goals is to load data as quickly as possible. Validation time depends on validation logic (maybe You have some non-MS components with long validation) and connection quality. Of course, FIRST TAKE A LOOK AT GUIDELINES in answer and only then think of validation overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the info! As it stands, my package includes cleanup procedures, and the whole thing for now takes about 30  minutes to run(have a couple of tables in the millions of rows to import daily). This package will be getting more and more complex, so I wanted to make sure if I needed to separate things, I do it early on.